# Charge of or for - the cost of something

Tags: phrases

my question is: If person A says: Do I have to pay additional for the delivery service? and **person B** replies : Yes, there would be an extra charge *FOR* or *OF* that? (the delivery)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The word "for" is used in such contexts to indicate the *reason* for the charge.  The word "of" is used in such contexts to indicate the *amount* of the charge.  Examples:

> There is an extra charge *for* delivery.
>
> There is an extra charge *of* ten dollars.
>
> There is an extra charge *of* ten dollars *for* delivery.